# Google Play won't install app for my customers. Is it Anomalous Permission issue? com.android.vending.BILLING

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing, play-billing-library

I tried to make a very small fix to one of my Android apps last week. Google Play said I couldn't upload the change because we were using the old in-app purchase library. I updated to the new v4 BillingClient library and submitted the app, but now tons of people are saying that Google Play refuses to install the update to their phone. And what is worse is that GP is telling them to DELETE and reinstall their app... and then refusing to reinstall the app leaving our customer without their paid app. And they are blaming us and leaving tons of 1 star reviews. :(

I can't get Google Play support to respond to me, so I'm desperately grabbing at straws as to what things I change that will maybe make the thing work again. The only issue that I can find is that the pre-launch report is complaining about `Anomalous Permission Usage` for requesting permission `com.android.vending.BILLING` but it is GOOGLE's v4 BillingClient code that is requesting that permission.

I've had all of the customers try resetting Google Play Cache and Data. None of it works.

I don't know what to do. How do I get Google Play to install the app? Or how can I find out why Google Play isn't installing the app?

Comment: Did you change your signing key, or move from old school self signing to Google App Signing?  Either of those would cause this issue.

Comment: No changes to the method of signing. Some people CAN install it (generally those on Android 11 and earlier), but it seems like people Android 12 cannot.